# Are there any examples of chemiluminescent reaction catalyzed by Group 1/2 metals?

Tags: biochemistry, catalysis, photochemistry

While researching chemiluminescent reaction that normally require enzymes but are replaced with metallic catalysts, as mentioned in this research paper: [Direct and Indirect Chemiluminescence: Reactions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiwl7CXitX2AhUVKX0KHeX0CO8QFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F1420-3049%2F26%2F24%2F7664%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw2q90BK2_UMSwzLKraZC-ZT) . I've bee trying to find similar papers on this, but with non-transition metals as catalysts; specifically group 1 and 2 metals. I appreciate the help

---

Answer (score 2):

Though I wouldn't term the use of $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{NaHCO3}$ in the [chemiluminescence of luminol](https://projects.ncsu.edu/project/chemistrydemos/Light/Luminol.pdf) a catalyst, *per se*, the reaction must proceed in an alkaline environment to produce light. However, "Transition metal complexes, such  as  the  hexacyanoferrate  ion are  used  to  catalyze  the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$."

Consider that transition metals have multiple oxidation states, so the metal ion can serve to transfer charges, and then return to the initial oxidation state, i.e., acting as a catalyst without being consumed. Group I and II generally have only a *single* oxidation state in solution, and would not do so.